# Hazelcast Hibernate Query Cache Region configuration

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast, second-level-cache, query-cache

I am running Hazelcast 3.11 in P2P mode and Hibernate-5.3. I have configured second level cache regions with expire policies for mine entities. Now I am trying to configure expire policy for mine Query caches, but issue is, I can not find out query cache default region name and not sure if it is configurable using hazelcast maps. I have tried next configs, but with no luck:

```
    eviction-policy: LFU
    in-memory-format: BINARY
    name: org.hibernate.cache.internal.*
    max-size: 1000
    max-size-policy: PER_NODE
    time-to-live: 10
    time-to-idle: 10
```

And

```
    eviction-policy: LFU
    in-memory-format: BINARY
    name: default-query-results-region
    max-size: 1000
    max-size-policy: PER_NODE
    time-to-live: 10
    time-to-idle: 10
```

Is it possible to configure Query Cache Region using hazelcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Depending on the cache region name set during the execution of a query, a map with this region name must be configured on the Hazelcast configuration. For instance, `default-query-results-region` will be used and must be configured for the following query:

```java
session.createQuery(QUERY_STRING).setCacheable(true);
```

and `custom-name` for the following:

```java
session.createQuery(QUERY_STRING).setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("custom-name");
```

---

You should configure the map config either programmatically or on hazelcast.xml such that:

```
<map name="default-query-results-region">
    <max-size>1000</max-size>
    <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
</map>    

<map name="custom-name">
    <max-size>1000</max-size>
    <time-to-live-seconds>10</time-to-live-seconds>
</map>
```

Keep in mind that in Hazelcast L2C, query results are not cached in distributed map but a local map. A basic clean up procedure is performed periodically for evictions based **only** on `max-size` and `time-to-live` criteria. Other options (eviction-policy, in-memory-format, idle-time etc.) will be ignored even if you set.

Comment: thanks for answer. Setting any configs for `name="default-query-results-region"` does not work for me, Did mention it in my original post. Even more, I am not able to find any map\cache with that name, nor in `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` neither in `SessionFactory.getStatistics()`

Comment: the only cache name that has to do anything with hibernate I am able to see is  `"default-update-timestamps-region"`

Comment: So can't you find statistics via `sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueryCacheHitCount()` or `sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueryCacheMissCount()`?

Comment: Can you try this: After configuring a map on Hazelcast, let's say "QueryMap";
`session.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(10).setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("QueryMap");`. Then you must see the region among the region names by: `factory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames()`

Comment: Okay, my bad. Worked for me with custom Query Region(btw I am using JPA Data Repository and it works with QuryHints too). And after that I did switch back to  `default-query-results-region` both in QuryHints and map config name, and it did worked too, though I was not able to make it work whole day. Well, looks like I was missing somethink. Thx for your help.